# VBA pasting row as image

Tags: vba, excel

[image]Just have a quick question regarding paste. I have a script that exports individual rows into a newly created workbook. However, the problem is that the pasted values are in the form of image. Additionally, the comments are skipped. I used the same code for pasting into other sheets of the same workbook, and there is no issue.

I can't seem to find the reason why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
Private Sub DC_1Month_Button_Click()
'Searches for crews working on MFDC (7343) and exports a new spreadsheet looking 3 weeks ahead for each person

If MsgBox("Export DC individual schedules?") = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo CleanFail

Dim nowCol As Integer, lastCol As Integer, endCol As Integer, crewRow As Integer
Dim masterSheet As Worksheet, newExcel As Object, newBook As Workbook, newSheet As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer
Dim currentName As String, currentProject As String

startRow = 3
endRow = UsedRange.Row - 1 + UsedRange.Rows.count
lastcoln = UsedRange.Column - 1 + UsedRange.Columns.count
Set masterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Schedule")

'Find columns for today and date 3 weeks after
nowCol = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, lastcoln)).Find(what:=Month(Date) & "/" & Day(Date) & "/" & Year(Date)).Column
endCol = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, lastcoln)).Find(what:=Month(DateAdd("d", 30, Date)) & "/" & Day(DateAdd("d", 30, Date)) & "/" & Year(DateAdd("d", 30, Date))).Column

'Disable screen flashing while doing copying and exports
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through crew members
For i = 3 To endRow
    'Store current row's values
    currentName = Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, "SA: ", "")
    currentProject = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value

    'Search the value from the Project column for the MFDC project number
    If InStr(1, currentProject, "7343") > 0 Then

    'Load schedule template
    Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    newExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    newExcel.Workbooks.Open "\\VALGEOFS01\SurveyProjectManagers\304Schedule\Templates\DC_3Week_Template.xlsx"
    Set newBook = newExcel.Workbooks(1)
    Set newSheet = newBook.Worksheets(1)

    'Copy and paste header rows
    masterSheet.Range(masterSheet.Cells(1, nowCol), masterSheet.Cells(2, endCol)).Copy 'Destination:=newSheet.Range("A1")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    newSheet.Range(newSheet.Cells(1, 6), newSheet.Cells(1, endCol - 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Copy and paste crew member's location
    masterSheet.Range(masterSheet.Cells(i, 2), masterSheet.Cells(i, 6)).Copy 'Destination:=newSheet.Range("A3")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    newSheet.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Copy schedule data for crew member
    masterSheet.Range(masterSheet.Cells(i, nowCol), masterSheet.Cells(i, endCol)).Copy
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    newSheet.Cells(3, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save individual's schedule
    With newBook
        .Title = currentName & " MFDC Schedule"
        .SaveAs Filename:="\\VALGEOFS01\SurveyProjectManagers\304Schedule\MFDC Individual Schedules\" & currentName & " MFDC Schedule " & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".xlsx", AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
        .Close (True)
    End With

    End If
Next i

CleanExit:
    MsgBox "Export complete"
    'Restore normal screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Resume CleanExit
    Resume

End Sub
```

Comment: You're using xlPasteAll one time but xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats the other times. Perhaps that's why?

Comment: Why are you starting a new Excel session at each iteration? You can stick to your current Excel session and use WorkBooks.Open() to open new workbooks and then close them with Close() method once you are done.

Comment: @Comintern, see edited post with picture.

Comment: @user3598756, different files are created and exported. Hence the individual sessions.

Comment: @Jbjstam, I'll try and test that.

Comment: @Francis, you can open, create and export different files staying in the same Excel session. Opening more Excel sessions will slow down the code. Furthermore at the end you are left with all of them open and you must eventually close them.